# different methods for calling c++ constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have seen an object constructor (for class A for example) be called `A()` and `A{}`
whats the difference? they both seem to do the same thing.

Comment: What does your C++ book say on this subject matter?

Comment: See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Comment: spend more time on reading constructors, you will get the answer yourself.

Comment: Why am I having trouble finding a duplicate?

Comment: @StoryTeller Looked for a duplicate myself, I suspect in the past these type of questions have been closed as too broad / read a book.

Comment: How about an example, that would help a lot

Answer (score 2):

> they both seem to do the same thing.

That is because they are two alternative syntaxes for the same thing.

> whats the difference?

- `A{}` did not exist until C++11.
- In a variable declaration, `A a()` is syntactically ambiguous with a function declaration, and language rules say that it is a function declaration. `A a{}` works around this limitation because it is not syntax for a function declaration. Now, this is a difference between `A a()` and `A a{}` and a reason for existence of `A a{}`, but there is no need for inconsistency of not having `A{}` as well.

Another argument for having `A{}` in addition to `A()` is that `A { arg1, arg2, ... };` is syntax for list initialization. For purposes of generic programming, it is necessary (or at least very useful) to also support an empty argument list: `A{}`.

Comment: _`A a()` is syntactically ambiguous with a function declaration_: Sometimes it's called "most vexing parse" after Scott Meyers, IIRC.